# how to pass json object in javascript function when every function is create dynamically with unique object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, parameters

I am creating dynamically `expandAnswerModal(responseObj)` function with passing data object of JSON  inside loop. But when I click on this function UI side get error while when I pass answer_url of Object I work fine but for whole JSON Object not work fine.
[I am attaching an image that contain both code UI view and inspected window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFr3F.png)

```
  for (i = 0; i < data.wdsResponse.results.length; i++) { 
                 var  responseObj=data.wdsResponse.results[i];
                 var answer={};
                    answer=responseObj.metadata;    
                    var source_url=responseObj.metadata.source_url;
                    var answer_url=responseObj.metadata.answer_url;
                    console.log(answer);
                    $("<div class='chatbot1-conversation-summary-message-body-border-bottom'><div class='chatbot1-conversation-summary-answer-title'><span onclick=**expandAnswerModal('"+answer_url+"')**>"+responseObj.metadata.header_snippet+"</span></div>"+
                    "<div class='chatbot1-conversation-summary-body-div wds-answer'><p onclick=**expandAnswerModal("+answer+")**>"+responseObj.metadata.text_snippet+"</p></div></div>").appendTo($(".chatbot1-conversations-body-conversations")["0"].lastChild);
                  outputContext=data.wcsResponse.context;

         }
```

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify` when you pass them and in your function you can parse it back using `JSON.parse`

Comment: It has also problem. Function parameter changed something that.

Comment: It has also problem. Function parameter changed something that.
**expandAnswerModal('{"score":1,"metadata":{"source_url":"http://wataswexnor801:8083/sources/ContactInformation.docx","source":"CONTACT_INFO","answer_url":"http://wattrfexnor801:8089/answers/A5019.htm" **

So I clicks on link that raise Invalid or unexpected token. I think it add more double and single quote so proper closing of function not getting.

Comment: Is any other way to add function with each #div with parameter function ?